# Even after enabling mod_pagespeed Google Pagespeed Insight shows optimize images. Why?

Tags: performance, optimization, mod-pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I have installed and enabled mod_pagespeed on my Apache server.

I have added following lines of code into the default configuration in pagespeed.conf file.

```
ModPagespeedRewriteLevel CoreFilters
ModPagespeedEnableFilters prioritize_critical_css
ModPagespeedEnableFilters sprite_images
ModPagespeedEnableFilters rewrite_images
ModPagespeedEnableFilters convert_png_to_jpeg,convert_jpeg_to_webp
ModPagespeedEnableFilters collapse_whitespace,remove_comments
```

Please note I have enabled `rewrite_images` filter, which should optimize images (as per their documentation).

Now if I test my site (http://kisan.co.in) for Google Pagespeed Insights, it still shows **Optimize Images**

Here is the screenshot
[image]

What could be the reason? Shouldn't images be optimized automatically?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are original images for slide5.jpg and slide6.jpg stored as PNG somewhere? According to https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/filter-image-optimize conversion from PNG to JPEG will occur as appropriate (i.e. if the image is not subject to JPEG noise artifacts). If your image is already JPEG though then there's not really a good way to go back because any JPEG noise artifacts would already be present

Comment: slide5.jpg and slide6.jpg are static images, I can optimize them and upload to server. I have installed mod_pagespeed because, I want to optimized user uploaded images (specifically with the name starting with thumb_). Why those images are not optimized automatically?

Comment: Read the page I linked, it says for example PNG to JPEG conversion occurs only if it detects that the JPEG artifacts will not occur. I don't think converting from JPEG to PNG could bring any space savings. To optimize them you probably would need to get the original (uncompressed) images as PNG or something like that

Comment: I've run into the same problem. Original JPG image right out of Lightroom, says it could save 99%, does nothing. I've tried other smaller images, and it works fine. :\

Comment: Are you sure you have mod_pagespeed running on your site?  What you describe should work.  One way to check is to run `curl -D- -s -o/dev/null http://kisan.co.in/ | grep X-Mod-Pagespeed`.  If you're running mod_pagespeed you should see `X-Mod-Pagespeed: VERSION`.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Have you been able to resolve this issue?

Comment: Me as well!!!  I asked a similar question here, in hope to get an answer.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36000888/image-optimization-using-google-pagespeed-insights-and-apache-mod-pagespeed

Comment: Same problem here. It seems no one really has an answer.

Comment: Right, I gave up on this and optimized images manually. :(

Comment: Same here... `rewrite_images` is on and working, but still not good enough according to pagespeed insights. You would think that Google's own tool should be the right tool for the job..